# On accelerated Proximal Gradient Methods

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am working on accelerated optimization scheme, which unified in the paper by Paul Tseng, "On Accelerated Proximal Gradient Methods for Convex-Concave Optimization". But unfortunately, it is sometimes difficult to understand. Is there any other source for this methods which is more clear and more explicit, especially about algorithms 3 and 4 of the paper. I think reading papers by Nesterov about this methods is more difficult. If there isn't. Can anyone explain where algorithms 3 and 4 come from?

Comment: Please be precise about you troubles with Algorithms 3 and 4. What don't you understand ?

Comment: I don't understand, for example, where equation (30), (weighted sum of previous gradients, l_f(x,y_i)) comes from and also, how equation 32 come from.

Comment: What's funny is that when we were creating TFOCS and writing its accompanying paper, I found the Tseng paper to be one of the _easier_ ones to understand in the field. I mean, compared to Nesterov... ;-)

Comment: Actually, after asking this question, I started to read almost any paper by Nesterov in this field. And I found it very much easier to understand. By Tseng paper, I mean just this paper: On accelerated proximal gradient methods for convex-concave optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out Boyd's monograph called Proximal Algorithms. Also, Vandenberghe's 236c notes are very helpful. Nesterov's textbook Introductory Lectures on Convex Optimization is another good resource for this material.

Comment: Wait, you're recommending Nesterov over Paul Tseng? :-) Ha! Make no mistake, a genius in the field, on whose shoulders we all stand. But man I have trouble wading through his derivations.

Comment: I agree with littleO's suggestion. After reading many of papers by both Nesterov ,Tseng And Others, I suggest to go directly through the papers by Nesterov. Start from "Smooth minimzation of non-smooth functions" and 2003 paper, and go through more recent papers.